# Precise heuristic for size of a uniform sample in $(\mathbb{Z} / N \mathbb{Z})^\times$

Tags: randomness, number-theory

I'm primarily a mathematicians dipping my toes into cryptography, and I have often seen/heard cryptographers use the heuristic that a uniformly random sample $a$ from $(\mathbb{Z} / N \mathbb{Z})^\times$ will be "large", or that $a \approx N$, without referring to a specific result.

I want to make sure I understand the precise heuristic here. Is the precise statement that the expected value of a uniformly random sample from $(\mathbb{Z} / N \mathbb{Z})^\times$ will be $N / 2$, and therefore linear in $N$. Thus for parameter selection (as an example), if we can choose $N$ and security relies on a uniformly random sample being sufficiently large, we can make $N$ large enough that with high probability we get a sample of sufficient size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even more can be said. Yes, in certain contexts all we care is that this quantity is a fixed positive constant (say $1/2$) times $N$.

While the multiplicative group has size $k:=\varphi(N)$ it is still true that the for large $N$ (cryptography is based on very large numbers) $k$ is typically very close to $N.$ For example, mostly $N$ is chosen to be a prime (for Diffie Hellman, e.g., when $k=N-1$) or a product of two large primes of roughly equal size for RSA, in which case $$k=N(1-\frac{1}{p})(1-\frac{1}{q})\approx N(1-\frac{2}{\sqrt N}).$$ So the average is indeed approximately $N/2$ for all practical purposes.

In addition, it is typical to measure this average logarithmically to the base 2, equal to the number of bits required to express this quantity, and in that case the difference between $\log N$ and $\log (N/2)$ is insignificant.

And measures of strength, such as algorithm complexities, are also measured logarithmically, so it all fits together nicely.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the difference essentially disappears when you look at the bit lengths. Very helpful!